# Convert a Javascript array to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

How do I take a javascript array

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

And convert it to a JSON object that looks like this

```
[
  {
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "value": 5
  },
  {
    "value": 6
  }
]
```

The closest I've come is using this

```js
JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, array));
```

But it gives me an output like this

```
{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6}
```

Comment: `array.map(value => ({ value }))`

Comment: Thanks @adiga when I was searching for a solution the results you posted didn't show up. Maybe I'll just consult you in the future.

Comment: @Bazilby Or you could consult the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_methods) and guides such as [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40195701/4642212).

Comment: [There’s no such thing as a “JSON Object”](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 1):

You could map the values by taking a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = array.map(value => ({ value }));

console.log(result);
```